# Is there a way to check if the textContent of a clicked button matches any of the values in my array?

Tags: javascript

I am making a Hangman game and I need help with my code. I want my code to have a function that takes the `textContent` property of a clicked button as the input, as well as another parameter that accepts the button itself. If the button that was clicked had the correct `textContent` to that in my array, then it should add a `correct` class, and if it was wrong, it should add a `wrong` class which makes the button red. My current code is not able to achieve this, instead, it gives **all** of the buttons the `wrong` class, please advice on the fix. Thank you.

**FUNCTION**

```
function checkAnswer(userChoice, userButton) {

    for (var i = 0; i < spellingOfWord.length; i++) {

        if (userChoice == spellingOfWord[i]) {

            userButton.classList.add("correct");

            setTimeout(function() {
                userButton.classList.add("hidden");
            }, 400);

        } else {
            userButton.classList.add("wrong");

            setTimeout(function() {
                userButton.classList.add("hidden");
            }, 400);

        }

        console.log(spellingOfWord[i]);
    }
}
```

**WHERE I AM CALLING THE FUNCTION**

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("button").length; i++) {

            document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

                checkAnswer(this.innerHTML, this);

            });
}
```

**EXAMPLE OF THE `spellingOfWord` ARRAY**

*Note: it's just an example.*

```
var spellingOfWord = gameWords[randomNumber].split("");

// In the browser, when console logging it, I get back:

["f", "o", "r"];

// Now I want to take the `textContent` of the button that was clicked and check against all the values of this array, but the code does not work, please advice.
```

Comment: Yes! Have a look at =>
 [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your for loop add the class at each iteration, so your button will have multiple wrong class and maybe some correct, what you need to do is assume that the class is wrong at start and if you find it you change it to correct and break the loop, then apply the class

```
let buttonClass = 'wrong'
for (var i = 0; i < spellingOfWord.length; i++) {

    if (userChoice == spellingOfWord[i]) {
        buttonClass = "correct";
        break;
    } 

    console.log(spellingOfWord[i]);
}

userButton.classList.add(buttonClass);

setTimeout(function() {
   userButton.classList.add("hidden");
}, 400);
```

or as suggested you can do

```
    if (spellingOfWord.includes(userChoice)) {
        userButton.classList.add("correct");

        setTimeout(function() {
            userButton.classList.add("hidden");
        }, 400);

    } else {
        userButton.classList.add("wrong");

        setTimeout(function() {
            userButton.classList.add("hidden");
        }, 400);

    }
```